# How can I use jq to sort this json file by the seconds value?

Tags: json, sorting, jq

I have this json data:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "request": {
                "metric": "CLOUDFREE_TIME_PERCENT", 
                "path": {
                    "fromPoint": {
                        "pointX": -94.2802, 
                        "pointY": 23.6687, 
                        "pointZ": 564843.0
                    }, 
                    "time": {
                        "seconds": 1582074350
                    }, 
                    "toPoint": {
                        "pointX": -118.2258, 
                        "pointY": 33.7501, 
                        "pointZ": -2.6077032e-08
                    }
                }, 
                "waveLength": 0
            }, 
            "response": {
                "dataSources": [], 
                "metricValue": 0.0, 
                "success": false
            }
        },
        {
            "request": {
                "metric": "CLOUDFREE_TIME_PERCENT", 
                "path": {
                    "fromPoint": {
                        "pointX": -20.6361, 
                        "pointY": 16.1509, 
                        "pointZ": 563070.9
                    }, 
                    "time": {
                        "seconds": 1582056949
                    }, 
                    "toPoint": {
                        "pointX": -20.6361, 
                        "pointY": 16.1509, 
                        "pointZ": 563070.9
                    }
                }, 
                "waveLength": 0
            }, 
            "response": {
                "dataSources": [], 
                "metricValue": 0.0, 
                "success": false
            }
        }, 
        {
            "request": {
                "metric": "CLOUDFREE_TIME_PERCENT", 
                "path": {
                    "fromPoint": {
                        "pointX": -94.2661, 
                        "pointY": 23.6066, 
                        "pointZ": 564826.16
                    }, 
                    "time": {
                        "seconds": 1582064349
                    }, 
                    "toPoint": {
                        "pointX": -118.2258, 
                        "pointY": 33.7501, 
                        "pointZ": -2.6077032e-08
                    }
                }, 
                "waveLength": 0
            }, 
            "response": {
                "dataSources": [], 
                "metricValue": 0.0, 
                "success": false
            }
        } 
    ]
}
```

I have been trying (but failing) to sort this by the "seconds" value. I've tried `jq '.results[].request.path.time|=sort_by(.seconds)' output.json` and it gives me the error `Cannot index number with string "seconds"`. I've tried all sorts of rearrangements of that command (and things like wrapping it with `map()`) as well to no avail. I'm starting to doubt if it's possible. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to sort the `time` object which, of course, is not possible. Sort the array instead:

```
jq '.results |= sort_by(.request.path.time.seconds)' output.json
```

Comment: Wow! So simple. Thank you! I was following the solutions to other similar questions on this site, and they led me astray. You saved me some headaches.